# Reg. Expression checks first letter of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check if the first character of a string is a letter or not. My regular expression is:

```
 '/^([a-zA-Z.*])$/'
```

This is not working. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z].*$/'
```

which checks if the first letter is in the alphabet and allows any character after that.

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried in Android. It accepts any character as first letter.

Comment: @jrhamza Works for me. Haven't tried in Android but I assume it uses Java's regex engine, which is mostly PCRE-ish, I think.

Answer (score 13):

Your expression does not need .* nor should it have the $

```
'/^([a-zA-Z])/'
```

In fact, if you don't need to know what this letter is, you could go even simpler:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z]/'

// These expressions are true
/^[a-zA-Z]/.test("Sample text")

var re = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]');
re.test('Sample text');
```

Comment: Possibly the OP intended `'/^([a-zA-Z].*)$/'`?

Comment: @Cameron: I'm not sure that regex makes any sense, let alone does what the OP wants.

Comment: +1 for "You're okay" but you also can just use `/^[a-z]/i` for the same price

Comment: @alpha123: It makes perfect sense, since all the characters are captured in the first group (as opposed to your answer which is equivalent to `'/^[a-zA-Z]/'`), however it doesn't seem to be what the OP was looking for after all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to single out the first letter with this `/^[a-zA-Z].*$/` from one of the above answers, but I didn't need the `.\*$` so I had `/^[A-J]/g` (working on my own assignment hence a-j).